# Double backslash on quotes when JSON stringifying an array of strings

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to stringify a JSON object that contains a string with quotes inside of it:

```
array = ['bar "foo"']
```

However, the string is created as: `'["bar \\"foo\\""]'` when I was hoping for something more along the lines of '["bar \"foo\""]'. Why are there two backslashes generated? Thanks

Comment: Why was the String created like that, exactly?

Comment: I called `JSON.stringify(array) and returned as that.

Comment: What would `'['"wat"']'` even mean?

Comment: That was just a placeholder for my actual string. That has double quotes surrounding a word.

Comment: how did you get the result as `'["bar \\"foo\\""]'`. console.log() ?

Comment: I put the result in an object I'm sending to the server and logged the object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why are there two backslashes generated?

Because backslashes must be escaped by backslashes to represent one single backslash in a string literal.

The string

```
'["bar \\"foo\\""]'
// or
"[\"bar \\\"foo\\\"\"]"
```

represents the value

```
["bar \"foo\""]
```

which is JSON for an array object containing the string value `bar "foo"`.

Probably the confusion was caused when you expected to see the value but the tool you used for that printed the string literal.